# Replace duplicate word in a string one by one

Tags: java, android, string

Hi am having string like below

String str =  "vishwa sgsu shishs sjishs vishwa  sjsjos vishwa";

I have to replace each occurrence like below

1. vishwa with xyz
2. vishwa with yzk
3. vishwa with jey

So my result string will look like below

"xyz sgsu shishs sjishs yzk  sjsjos jey"

I tried with replaceFirst(), replace() methods, but not working.

How can i do it.?

Comment: What are you replacing here?

Comment: What's not working? Can you show us the code?

Comment: `newString = string.replaceFirst("vishwa","xyz")` should be the right approach, whats not working?

Comment: i tried with replacefirst("vishwa"," xyz"), replacefirst("vishwa"," yzk") but only in first cal its replacing first occurrence after that its not working

Comment: Is it - by any chance - possible that you forget to use the result of the first `replaceFirst` as input for the second one and instead used the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code and check your output.

```
  String str = "vishwa sgsu shishs sjishs vishwa sjsjos vishwa";

  String strNewString = str.replace("vishwa","xyz");
  strNewString = strNewString.replace("vishwa","yzk");
  strNewString = strNewString.replace("vishwa","jey");
```

Now use strNewString as future use.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something more robust, use this -

```
String original = "vishwa sgsu shishs sjishs vishwa sjsjos vishwa";
String s = "vishwa";
String [] replacements = { "xyz", "yzk", "jey" };
for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
    if (original.contains(s)) {
        original = original.replaceFirst(s, replacements[i]);
    } else {
          break;
    }
}
System.out.println(original);
```

If you need to replace more strings, the loop will do the work.

Comment: @Unihedron - You are right, I've corrected my answer, but you are faster :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
String someString = "vishwa sgsu shishs sjishs vishwa sjsjos vishwa";   
someString = someString.replaceFirst("vishwa","xyz");
someString = someString.replaceFirst("vishwa","yzk");
someString = someString.replaceFirst("vishwa","jey");
```

Comment: You mean `String` ... not `string` ... in case someone will copy & paste

Comment: yes i changed that

Answer (score -1):

Since the replaceFirst creates a new string you can do it by

`String result = str.replaceFirst("vishwa", "xyz")
                    .replaceFirst("vishwa", "yzk")
                    .replaceFirst("vishwa", "jey")`